# how do I remove write-protection from a Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine image?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I've opened my first Compute Engine VM (Linux in this case), added what I need (applications for instance), and created an Image from it.
I can then use that Image to spin up other VMs.

However the files I've put in the image then seem to be write-protected, and I can't alter them. How do I remove this write-protection?

If that's not possible, how can I change the image?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to access the custom image and modifying it without connecting to the VM-Instance. As per my understanding you can attach the custom image to the new VM-instance, modify that image further as per your requirements and then make another image and assign it another version number . Please see the [link-1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#setting_families) for Setting image versions in an image family.

Comment: But that's the problem, when I "attach the custom image to the new VM-instance", those directories on the new VM-instance are read-only and I can't change them....

Comment: We need to investigate your issue and to check the logs and other information. It is therefore suggested that please open an [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and share your project ID so that we can investigate your issue.